# Inverse of logarithmic function for an microphone input level

Tags: javascript, math, logarithm

I'm trying to write a slider that has logarithmic scaling to control a microphone RMS threshold.

I have written the function below that may be ghastly (maths is not my strong suit) but does seem to do the logarithmic scaling that I want. However, I now need to display the RMS level in a bar that uses the scale, so I need to invert this function.

```
const rmsLogarithmicScale = (value, max) => {
    const log = ((100 - (Math.log((1 - value) * 100) / 4.605170185988092) * 100) / 100) * max;
    return log === Infinity ? max : log;
};

console.log(rmsLogarithmicScale(0.5, 0.05)); // Result: 0.007525749891599539
console.log(rmsLogarithmicScale(0.5, 300)); // Result: 45.15449934959723
```

```
const rmsLogarithmicScaleInverse = (rms, max) => {
    // I have literally no idea where to start...
}

rmsLogarithmicScaleInverse(0.007525749891599539, 0.05); // Result: 0.5
```

Is there a kind mathematician out there who can help me to work this through?

Comment: Just to be clear, you know that `* max` part gets done after the division, right? It's not `blah / (100 * max)` but `(blah / 100) * max`. With that said, no need for a mathematician, just ask [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=invert+%28100+-+%28log%28%281+-+a%29+*+100%29+%2F+4.605170185988092%29+*+100%29+%2F+100) to do it for you.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm not exactly sure what I've written. It maxes out at the value I want and has finer granularity toward the end I want it. I'll give Wolfram Alpha a look, it might help me sort out both functions.

Comment: Remember that if you're not sure of what you've written, you have no idea whether or not your code works. All you know is that it _seems_ to work. So here's an obvious question: we can trivially get the inverse of `rmsLogarithmicScale(value,max)`: it's `value`. You already have that, because that's what you started with. Why not just "compute nothing" and instead plot your starting values?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans seeming to work might be good enough in this instance. The lower end of the scale needs to be a little more finely tuned, I have a slider that shows that is working ok, so I can drag it from one end to the other and see the values. This value is the RMS threshold. The problem is that the audio features I'm extracting need to be displayed in a bar to show whether the RMS level breaches the threshold. When I get the RMS value I'm not sure how to map it back to the scale.

Comment: What I'm trying to do could be completely wrong. It's likely an xy problem.

Comment: I gave you the link that literally solves the maths for "mapping it back", so that part's sorted. Whether you have an XY problem is a different matter: the most obvious question of course would be "why are you writing your own code at all?" because it seems unlikely that no one's written a DSP package in JS over the last 25 years of JS, and 5 years of Node.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans lol, thanks so much! I just read Wolfram Alpha I didn't click the link. Looks great I'll see if I can make sense of it.

Comment: The functional inverse of a logarithm is a corresponding exponential.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I did read that elsewhere I tried to just reverse my logic and use `Math.exp()` I really didn't know what I was doing. Andy seems to have got it, I'll just port it over to JavaScript

Comment: You should start by simplifying to `const log = -Math.log(1 - value) / Math.log(100) * max;`

Comment: @Bergi Thanks so much! That's so much cleaner. I'll see if I can invert that one myself.

Comment: @Sarcoma It'll become even easier if you recognise that division between two logarithms as [a change of base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base) from a base-100 logarithm.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the link, I'm still none the wiser. I understand code and just about get by with maths as I need to. I just really struggle to read equations, it's the bane of my life. Looks like I got it working with the simplified version you suggested and managed to work out the inverse on my own, so I'm pretty chuffed with that. Thanks to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answer was provided in Java, JavaScript example is below the original*

This is the inverse of the calculation expressed in intermediate forms.

(But I prefer your discussion in comments - just adding this since it was fun.)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double v = rmsLogScale(0.5,0.05);
    System.out.println("v = " + v);                // prints 0.007525749891599539
    double iv = invRmsLogScale(v, 0.05);
    System.out.println("iv = "+iv);                // 0.499999999999999994

}

static double rmsLogScale(double v, double m) {
    double x1 = (1 - v) * 100.;
    double x2 = Math.log(x1);
    double x3 = x2 / 4.605170185988092;
    double x4 = x3 * 100.;
    double x5 = 100. - x4;
    double x6 = x5 / 100. * m;

    return x6;
}

static double invRmsLogScale(double lg, double m) {
    double x5 = (lg * 100) / m;
    double x4 = (100. - x5);
    double x3 = x4 / 100.;
    double x2 = x3 * 4.605170185988092;
    double x1 = Math.exp(x2);
    double x0 = 1 - ((x1) / 100.);
    return x0;
}
```

---

**JavaScript**

```
const rmsLogScale = (v, m) => {
    const x1 = (1 - v) * 100.0;
    const x2 = Math.log(x1);
    const x3 = x2 / 4.605170185988092;
    const x4 = x3 * 100.0;
    const x5 = 100.0 - x4;
    return x5 / 100.0 * m;
};

const inverseRmsLogScale = (lg, m) => {
    const x5 = (lg * 100) / m;
    const x4 = (100.0 - x5);
    const x3 = x4 / 100.0;
    const x2 = x3 * 4.605170185988092;
    const x1 = Math.exp(x2);
    return 1 - ((x1) / 100.0);
};

console.log(rmsLogScale(0.5, 0.5));
console.log(rmsLogScale(0.5, 300));

console.log(inverseRmsLogScale(rmsLogScale(0.5, 0.5), 0.5));
console.log(inverseRmsLogScale(rmsLogScale(0.3, 300), 300));
```

Comment: Note that the question is about JavaScript, though. Not Java. There are only decimals in JS, so no need for `.` at the end of any number, nor function return typing, nor variable typing (although in modern JS, you probably want to use `const` for each var you're allocating in those functions)

Comment: Actually question is one of Math expressed as javascript and answer expressed as java.

Comment: Java is fine, any language is fine lol. Thanks so much for this.

Comment: Once I have it working I'll update the answer to include a JavaScript example.

Comment: Updated to: `double x0 = 1 - ((x1) / 100.);`. Looks to work perfectly thanks a lot. Next time I'll list out my calculations like this. So much easier to see the inverse that way.

Answer (score 1):

After @Bergi suggested I try simplifying my original function, I rewrote the function in the style of @Andy and have managed to invert it too.

> You should start by simplifying to const log = -Math.log(1 - value) / Math.log(100) * max; — Bergi

```
const logScale = (value, max) => {
    const x1 = 1 - value;
    const x2 = -Math.log(x1);
    const x3 = x2 / Math.log(100);
    const x4 = x3 * max;
    return x4;
};

const altInverseRmsLogScale = (lg, max) => {
    const x4 = lg / max;
    const x3 = x4 * Math.log(100);
    const x2 = Math.exp(-x3);
    const x1 = 1 - x2;
    return x1;
};

console.log(logScale(0.7, 300)); // 4.727557716909737
console.log(inverseLogScale(logScale(0.7, 300), 300)); // 0.07000000000000006
```

**Terse Version**

```
const logScale = (value, max) => (-Math.log(1 - value) / Math.log(100)) * max;

const inverseLogScale = (lg, max) => 1 - Math.exp(-(lg / max * Math.log(100)));
```

**Terser Version**

```
const logScale = (value, max) => (-Math.log(1 - value) / Math.log(100)) * max;
const inverseLogScale = (lg, max) => 1 - Math.pow(100, -lg / max);

console.log(logScale(0.6, 300));
console.log(inverseLogScale(logScaleTwo(0.6, 300), 300));
```

https://repl.it/@sarcoma/log-scale

**Final Function**

I also needed to handle `Infinity` being returned when `value === max`.

```
const logScale = (value, max) => {
    const log = (-Math.log(1 - value) / Math.log(100)) * max;
    return log === Infinity ? max : log;
};
const inverseLogScale = (lg, max) => 1 - Math.pow(100, -lg / max);
```

Comment: `y = Math.log(x) / Math.log(100)` is `y = log(100, x)`, and its inverse is `x = Math.pow(100, y)`

Comment: @Bergi Thanks again. Looks like I got there. Now I just need to work out if that's actually what I needed to do in the first place. Was fun to work through anyway. Your guidance and patience are greatly appreciated.